# How can I modify array fields in place?

Tags: rethinkdb

Let's say I have this object:

```
{
    "id":  "1a48c847-4fee-4968-8cfd-5f8369c01f64" ,
    "sections": [
    {
        "id": 0 ,
        "title":  "s1"
    } ,
    {
        "id": 1 ,
        "title":  "s2"
    } ,
    {
        "id": 2 ,
        "title":  "s3"
    }
    ]
}
```

How can I directly change 2nd title "s2" to other value? without loading the object and save again? Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to do this update in ReQL or something else? Please be more specific.

Comment: using javascript api. ReQL or not doesn't matter if it works. : )

Comment: It matters if there are over 20 different languages it supports

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation? [http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#update](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/#update)

Comment: The examples only shows update root fields or non-array fields and it works. but when I try row.array[i].property = value, it doesn't work. that's why I want a solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update plus the [changeAt](http://rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/change_at/) term:

```js
r.table('blog').get("1a48c847-4fee-4968-8cfd-5f8369c01f64").update(function(row){
  return {
    sections: row('sections').changeAt(1,
        row('sections')(1).merge({title: "s2-modified"}))
  }
}
```

The above is good if you already know the index of the item you want to change. If you need to find the index, then update it, you can use the `.offsetsOf` command to look up the index of the element you want:

```js
r.table('table').get("1a48c847-4fee-4968-8cfd-5f8369c01f64").update(function(row){
  return row('sections').offsetsOf(function(x){
    return x('title').eq('s2')
  })(0).do(function(index){
    return {
        sections: row('sections').changeAt(index,
           row('sections')(index).merge({title: "s2-modified"}))
    }
  })
})
```

Edit: modified answer to use `changeAt`

Comment: Please not that `indexesOf` is nowadays called `offsetsOf`.

Comment: @MikaelLirbank fixed! Thanks.