# Rethinkdb remove string from array

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, reql

Given an array and data structure as below, I want to remove any values that match from the *removeVals* from the table field *tags*.  I've found a solution for changing, and tried with the *deleteAt*, but got an *indexesOf is not a function* error.

`var removeTags = ["val1", "val3"];`

```
{
  name: "test1",
  tags: ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4", "val5"]
}
```

so I should be left with:

```
{
  name: "test1",
  tags: ["val2", "val4", "val5"]
}
```

My code so far:

```
var removeTags = ["val1", "val2"]
r.db('test').table('data').get('test1').update(function(row) {
  return row('tags').indexesOf(function(rl) {
    return r.expr(removeTags).contains(rl)
  })(0).do(function(idx) {
    return {
      roles: row('tags').deleteAt(idx)
    }
  })
});
```

This is the [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27508480/how-can-i-modify-array-fields-in-place) I was using as a reference.  Any help would be appreciated, many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nevermind, I've found the answer and it was far easier than I thought, I was over complicating things too much!

```
var removeTags = ['val1', 'val2'];
r.db('test').table('data').get('test1')
  .update({tags: r.row('tags').difference(removeTags)});
```

Anyway, hope this helps others